# How to convert and install Android app to blackberry 10?

Tags: android, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

From the Eclipse plugin, installed via [instructions in Runtime for Android apps documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/install_plugin_prerequisites_1895476_11.html), I tried to convert my Android app with BlackBerry plug-in for ADT, but I got this error message:

```
Failed to deploy project android-app-com-2
Info: Sending request: Install
Info: Action: Install
Info: File size: 2989786
Info: Installing ...
Info: Processing 2989786 bytes
Info: Progress 0%...
Info: Progress 50%...
Info: Progress 100%...
actual_dname::com.app.durbon.testEJjhp8tKy1bZX0fw0v7WXIU
actual_id::testEJjhp8tKy1bZX0fw0v7WXIU
actual_version::1.81.4202.0
result::failure -110
```

I have no idea what failure -110 means and actual_dname

My package is com.app.durbon, but appears .test i have no idea why

Comment: You could try the on-line packager https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/Using_the_bb_packager_1873331_11.html

Comment: thanks,i found this resource http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Tablet-OS-Graphical-Aid/ta-p/1207067 i'll try

Answer (score 3):

You can check using online tool to convert android .apk file into .bar file of blackberry.
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/bpaa/

Answer (score 0):

Just try the [graphical aid tool](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/BlackBerry-Tablet-OS-Graphical-Aid/ta-p/1207067). if you are familiar with console, you can [use command line tool](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/).

Answer (score 0):

Some important things to pay attention when running Android apps in BlackBerry are:

- You must have a device or a emulator target on which to deploy. If you are using devices, only BlabkBerry 10 haves the runtime. If you are using simulators, use the ones in [BlackBerry Dev](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/);
- The BB's Andorid runtime only supports versions of Froyo (2.3) or above;
- When using BB's simulator, you must be connected to it via Socket like manner. You can configure it in Window/Preference/BlackBerry/Target;
- By the error you've got, I can wonder if it is in wrong version!